# Probability in Poker of a pair

Tags: probability

When calculating probability of a pair, this is what I tried:

$$\frac{52 \times 3 \times 48 \times 44 \times 40}{52 \times 51 \times 50 \times 49 \times 48}$$

However, it is $10$ times smaller than the correct answer. Why is this, and what did I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Maths written in MathJax is better for the site. I've done it for you this time but here's a reference: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference it's really useful for formatting maths.

Comment: @RoshanKlein-Seetharaman Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the probability to don't get a pair is

$$\frac{52\cdot 48\cdot 44\cdot 40\cdot 36}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48}$$

then the probability to have *at least* a pair in hand is

$$1-\frac{52\cdot 48\cdot 44\cdot 40\cdot 36}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48}\approx 49\%$$

To calculate the probability to have *exactly one pair* we can consider as an alternative

- number of pairs $13\cdot \binom{4}{2}$
- number of other three cards for each pair $\frac{48\cdot 44 \cdot 40}{3!}$
- numbers of hands $\binom{52}{5}$

then

$$\frac{13\cdot \binom{4}{2}\frac{48\cdot 44 \cdot 40}{3!}}{\binom{52}{5}}\approx 42\%$$

Comment: OP is looking for the probability of exactly one pair in the hand.

Comment: Oh yes any pair I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying the second card drawn has to match the first card drawn, then the rest can't match anything drawn so far.  There are $10$ ways to select the two cards that will pair, which is what you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Another way considering any first card drawn and then the probability of producing just one pair in the next 4 cards is..........
$$(\frac{3}{51}\cdot\frac{48}{50}\cdot\frac{44}{49}\cdot\frac{40}{48})+2(\frac{48}{51}\cdot\frac{3}{50}\cdot\frac{44}{49}\cdot\frac{40}{48})+3(\frac{48}{51}\cdot\frac{44}{50}\cdot\frac{3}{49}\cdot\frac{40}{48})+4(\frac{48}{51}\cdot\frac{44}{50}\cdot\frac{40}{49}\cdot\frac{3}{48})$$

$= 42.3\%$